# I am working on selenium webdriver and want to set the current date

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried doing this:

```
Date date = new Date();
String lastDate = (date.toString().trim());
// display time and date using toString()
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

but here the system date is being displayed as:

```
"Wed Apr 13 15:39:50 IST 2016"
```

and all I need is "MM/dd/yyyy"

Comment: why is this question tagged with selenium?

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

//get current date time of system with `Date()`

```
Date date = new Date();

String date1= dateFormat.format(date);  // Now format the date

// Print the Date
System.out.println("Current date and time is " +date1);
```

for detail: http://www.alltestingstuff.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to format it:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

//get current date time with Date()
Date date = new Date();

// Now format the date
String dateFormatted= dateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```